# balance equals to zero when reinstalling app

Tags: balances, iota-recovery

I tried to get my iotas in a new app isntance in another cell phone and the balance is zero, sync manually or snapshot transition does fix the issue, it loops in findings 0 iotas.

I can see the balance ok with querying the tangle.

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

please make sure to type the seed correctly. If just one of the 81 characters si wrong you might access to a seed with an empty balance.

Eventually exporting the **SeedVault** from your other phone and importing it to this one.
To export your seed vault in Trinity on mobile go to **Settings** - **Account Management** - **Export SeedVault**

For further and faster help by the community visit our #help channel on discord (https://discord.iota.org)

Please remember **that IOTA Foundation members will never ask for your seed when assisting you**. Please keep your seed safe!